# What is the best way to establish sqlite connection in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have seen lots of examples related sqlite connection. But there is no any proper code I have still found. Anyone please describe step by step sqlite connection process with all possibilities ?

Answer (score 2):

1. First, you need to create a database. 
   You do this by creating a DatabaseHelper class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper.
   Override the onCreate() and onUpgrade() methods:

   ```
   public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

       public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
           super(context, Config.DATABASE_NAME, null, Config.DATABASE_VERSION);
       }

       @Override
       public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
           MyTable.onCreate(db);
       }

       @Override
       public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
           MyTable.onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
       }
   }
   ```

When your app starts for the first time, Android OS will call your onCreate() method to create the database and your table.

2. Create MyTable class.

   ```
   public class MyTable {

       // Database table
       public static final String TABLE_NAME = "mytable";

       // Create statement
       private static final String SQL_CREATE_MY_TABLE = 
           "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + MyTableContract.SQL_CREATE_COLUMN_CLAUSE + ");";


       public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_MY_TABLE);
       }

       public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
           db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
           onCreate(db);
       }
   }
   ```

Here you create the table and upgrade it. Create just delegates to a Contract class. It's a good practice to extract all column activity into a Contract class. Upgrade, in most cases it's ok to drop and re-create the table, unless you want to preserve some data like Login.

3. Create your Table Contract.

   ```
   public class MyTableContract {

   // COLUMNS
   public static final String COLUMN_ID    = "_id";
   public static final String COLUMN_NAME  = "name";
   public static final String COLUMN_AGE   = "age";


   // Create clause
   public static final String SQL_CREATE_COLUMN_CLAUSE = 
       COLUMN_ID       + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
       COLUMN_NAME     + " TEXT, " +
       COLUMN_AGE      + " INTEGER";

   // Query projection
   public static final String[] QUERY_PROJECTION =
   {
       COLUMN_ID,
       COLUMN_NAME,
       COLUMN_AGE
   };

   // Selection clause - return all rows
   public static final String SELECTION_CLAUSE = null;

   // Selection arguments
   public static final String[] SELECTION_ARGS = null;

   // Use default sort order
   public static final String QUERY_SORT_ORDER = null;
   }
   ```

This is where you specify which columns you want created and which columns you want returned when you query the database.

4. Insert / Query. 
   Then wherever you want to insert/query the database, you can do this:

   ```
   // Create a Database Helper
   private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());

   // Get the writable database to Insert
   SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   values.put(MyTableContract.COLUMN_NAME, "eduard");
   values.put(MyTableContract.COLUMN_AGE,   32);
   long insertId = database.insert(MyTable.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

   // Get the readable database to Query
   SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor cursor = database.query(MyTable.TABLE_NAME, MyTableContract.QUERY_PROJECTION, MyTableContract.COLUMN_AGE + " = 32", null, null, null, null);
   cursor.moveToFirst();
   String nameReturned = cursor.getString(0);
   cursor.close();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

try to create two different files one for database handler and another for simply writes your queries.In your database handler extend it to SQLiteOpenhelper and implement methods.in oncreate() method create database as per your requirement and in your query file create methods as per need and write queries inside methods and call their object in your activities.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Database_Helper {
   private Context context;
public static String DB_name = "demo.sqlite";
Demo_DBHelper dh;
SQLiteDatabase sdb;

private static class Demo_DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public Demo_DBHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_name, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("On Create Called");
        db.execSQL("Create TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Contact_Detail(mid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name VARCHAR,phonenumber VARCHAR)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Contact_Detail");

        // db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CommunityDetails");
    }

}

public Database_Helper(Context c) {
    context = c;
}

public Database_Helper Open() throws SQLiteException {
    dh = new Demo_DBHelper(context);
    sdb = dh.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    dh.close();
}

public void clearData() {
    sdb.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Contact_Detail");

}

public Cursor getContactDetail() {

    String st = "SELECT * from Contact_Detail";

    Cursor rs_message = sdb.rawQuery(st, null);
    return rs_message;

}

public void add_contact(String name, String phonenumber) {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("name", name);
    cv.put("phonenumber", phonenumber);
    sdb.insert("Contact_Detail", null, cv);

}

public void removephone(int phonenumber) {

    String str = "SELECT * FROM Contact_Detail where phonenumber='"
            + phonenumber + "' ";
    Cursor rs_message = sdb.rawQuery(str, null);
    if (rs_message.moveToFirst()) {

        String st = "DELETE FROM Contact_Detail where phonenumber='"
                + phonenumber + "' ";
        sdb.execSQL(st);
    }

}

public void update_contactdetail(String phonenumber, String name) {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("name", "" + name);

    sdb.update("Contact_Detail", cv, "phonenumber=?",
            new String[] { phonenumber });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DBAdapter {
    //User Master
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_Email = "email";
    public static final String KEY_PASS = "pass";



    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TEST_DB";
    private static final int DATABASE_VIRSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table User_Mst(id integer primary key,email text,pass text);";

    private Context context = null;
    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context con) {
    this.context = con;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }
    private class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VIRSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);


    } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS User_Mst");



    onCreate(db);
    }
    }

    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
    }
    public void close() {
    DBHelper.close();
    }
    public long insertuser(int i,String mail,String pass) {

    ContentValues init = new ContentValues();
    init.put(KEY_ROWID, i);
    init.put(KEY_Email, mail);
    init.put(KEY_PASS, pass);
    return db.insert("User_Mst", null, init);
    }




    public boolean deleteUser(long rowid) {
    return db.delete("User_Mst", KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowid, null) > 0;
    }



    public Cursor getuser() {
    return db.query("User_Mst", new String[] { KEY_ROWID,KEY_Email,
    KEY_PASS }, null, null, null, null, null);
    }





    public Cursor getUser(long rowid) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mycursor = db.query(true, "User_Mst", new String[] { KEY_ROWID,KEY_Email,KEY_PASS },
    KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowid, null, null,    null, null, null);
    if (mycursor != null) {
    mycursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mycursor;
    }

    public boolean updateuser(long rowid,String mail,String pass) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_Email, mail);
    args.put(KEY_PASS,pass);
    return db.update("User_Mst", args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowid, null) > 0;
    }

    }
```